# dropdown filter - Why is e.target.value undefined onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, dropdown

Im not sure why the value of e.target.value is undefined.

```
type State = {
  filterCountry: string,
};

export default class Developers extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      developers: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('API').then(features => {
      return features.json();
    }).then(data => {
      let developers = data.features.map((info) => {
          const developer_info = {
              id: info.id,
              name: info.properties.name,
              skills: info.properties.skills_full,
              location: info.properties.location,
              description: info.properties.description,
              email: info.properties.email,
              country: info.properties.continent
          }
          return developer_info;
      });

      this.setState({ developers: developers})

    })

  }

    filter(e) {
    this.setState({filter: e.target.value})
  }

  filterCountry(e){
    this.setState({filterCountry: e.target.value})
  }




  render() {

       if(this.state.filterCountry){
         developers = developers.filter( developer =>
         developer.country
         .includes(this.state.filterCountry))
       }


return (


          <ControlSelect
            id="country-select"
            onChange={this.filterCountry.bind(this)} value={this.state.filterCountry}
            options={options_dd2}
          />
        </div>
```

trying to follow this example 
[create a dropdown in react to show/hide fetch data based on object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103866/create-a-dropdown-in-react-to-show-hide-fetch-data-based-on-object-class)

Comment: What is `ControlSelect`? Does it set the `e.target.value` property? Show the complete `e` contents. PS: it would also be helpful if you posted a properly indented code.

Comment: Why the value is `this.state.filterCountry ` and it's not in the state constructor

Comment: we can Ignore ControlSelect, its does not set a e.target.value property

Comment: @liam I'm not sure.. im kinda muddling my way through this, .. not 100% sure of everything

Comment: Well, create a `filterCountry` state  like this `filterCountry: 'value'` in your construcor.

Comment: adding filterCountry: 'value', only makes developers .. not defined

Comment: Does `ControlSelect` is a child component or it's coming from a package?

Comment: its coming from a package .. i wrote. but its only making some front end styles.. not interfering

Comment: Well, Does `ControlSelect` creating elements or it's just for styles?

Comment: What is the name of this package?

Comment: its a private package for my company, .. it creates the dropdown

Comment: i updated with an example im trying to follow

Comment: I saw it, it's about league of legend game which is my favorite game :D, I don't see in your code a select element as well options elements

Comment: the options are stored in a variable in the options prop.. and the select is being generated by ControlSelect

Comment: Well, does each option element has his own value attribute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170495/discussion-between-tallgirltaadaa-and-liam).

Comment: What is `e.target.tagName` in 'filter` and `filterCountry` ? If it is "OPTION", continue chatting...

Comment: traktor, .. i cant get any info out of filter or filterCountry, bc i keep getting Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks the problem is from `ControlSelect` it doesn't set the `e.target.value` property.

I believe if you just use a Select element with options will works

```
return (
         <div>
   <select onChange={this.filterCountry.bind(this)} value={this.state.filterCountry}>
          <option value="value">All Champs</option>
          <option value="Assassin">Assassin</option>
          <option value="Fighter">Fighter</option>
          <option value="Mage">Mage</option>
          <option value="Marksman">Marksman</option>
          <option value="Support">Support</option>
          <option value="Tank">Tank</option>
        </select>
       </div>
   )
```

Comment: well.. its weird, bc this code.. does something to developers.. that makes it undefined ..

Comment: This code shouldn't ruin the developers state, maybe there's something else did that.

Comment: i found the issue there, .. one last thing, .. in the console, it always shows the selection prior and not the current one, .. for the first time you click the dropdown, selection is undefined.